# How to copy a specific format file from sftp to local using Python

Tags: python, csv, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

```
import paramiko
import os

paramiko.util.log_to_file('logfile.log')

host = "100.10.89.23"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
password = "pass"
username = "user"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

filepath = '/import/TMP'
localpath = 'F:\\Projects\\Test'
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

ftp_priv_key is not required to connect to sftp.
Suppose I have 10 files in the given sftp path, out of which 6 files are in `csv` format and other or in different format. My requirement is to copy only the `csv` format files.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do something like:

```
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
for filename in sftp.listdir(filepath):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        sftp.get(filename, localpath)
```

Comment: Making changes the way you suggest & while running the code i got the following error:
1. Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 721
 size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
2.Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 695
file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size
3.Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 413
t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
4.Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 730
 return self._read_response(num)
5. Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 781
self._convert_status(msg)

Comment: 6. Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py" line 807
raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)

Comment: Stephen Rauch,,
Its really appreciating if you suggest what's missing?

Comment: This does not help.  Which line failed?